# Bootstrap modal not showing. Only background becomes black

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modal. The triggrer is like this:

```
<a id="add-feed-button"  role="button" data-toggle="modal" href="#add-feed-form" class="btn pull-right btn-success"   style="margin-left:5px; margin-top:-4px;">Add new</a>
```

and my modal:

```
 <div id="add-feed-form" class="form-feed modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
this is modal.
</div>
```

Problem is that only the backdrop becomes black but no modal appears.

I have included bootstrap.js and also bootstrap.min.css. I have used modals quite a times but this is a strange problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove `.hide` class from `div#add-feed-form` and then it will work fine.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/mVfCe/)

Comment: A question I have is why isn't the `hide` class needed when the **[Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)** imply it should be there?

Comment: because hide class is already mentioned in the Bootstrap docs. which makes it hide by it.

Comment: @vogomatix, because the `hide` class is used in bootstrap 2.X and removed in bootstrap 3.X. I think the user is tyring to port the 2.X code to 3.X so hence having the issue with .hide . Hope it helps ! ;)

Comment: Reference : 
if the user is trying to port from 2.X to 3.X
then you can use two classes, 
one is `hide` and the other one is `hidden`.
So, in this way you don't have worry about it.

Comment: I do not have the hide class and I am using bootstrap 3 - any idea ? I am also using angularjs